# How to carry out the 'and' operation in laravel 4.1 with multiple parameters

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4

I wish to know how to write the following in laravel:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = $id AND item_category = $cat AND item_price = $price;
```

$id, $cat and $price are dynamically passed unto the query.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eloquent

```
Item::where('item_id', $id)
->where('item_category', $cat)
->where('item_price', $price)
->get();
```

Fluent

```
DB::table('items')
->where('item_id', $id)
->where('item_category', $cat)
->where('item_price', $price)
->get();
```